# Async function works with a callback does not work with await

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback, es6-promise

I am trying to integrate into my code an async library function. It works fine as:

```
client.checkPermission(checkPermissionRequest, (err, response) => {
  if (err || response?.permissionship !== HAS_PERMISSION) {
    const e = err || new Error('You do not have access to event:', id);
    res.code(404).send({ error: e });
  }
});
```

I want to rewrite it in an "await form" and this does not work. I have been trying:

```
const response = await client.checkPermission(checkPermissionRequest);
```

When I run the await code, it fails with: `Error: Incorrect arguments passed`.

Why could this be happening and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` doesn't magically make a callback-based API return a promise.

You can however, wrap the call in a promise:

```
const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.checkPermission(checkPermissionRequest, (err, response) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        return resolve(response);
    });
});
```

This is called ["promisification"](https://javascript.info/promisify). If you're a little confused as to how `resolve` and `reject` work, maybe the [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#examples) in MDN could help with that.

Answer (score 1):

In Node environments you can use the node utility [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) to convert the calling conventions of a node style function taking an (error, value) callback  as their last argument, into a function that returns a promise without taking a callback argument:

```
  const util = require('node:util');  //   **OR**
  import {promisify} from 'node:util';

  client.checkPermission = util.promisify( client.checkPermission)
```

And then call with

```
  const response = await client.checkPermission(checkPermissionRequest);
```

---

**Core module imports**

```
 import {promisify} from 'node:util';
```

imports the promisify utility in a script module. From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#builtin-modules)

> Core modules provide named exports of their public API. A default export is also provided which is the value of the CommonJS exports